# Convex function as supremum

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, convex-analysis

I was reading in a  text which stated:

> Let $G$ open interval, $c:G \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ convex function. Let $\Delta_{u,v} := \frac{c(v)-c(u)}{v-u}$ for $u<v$. Then $D_{-c}(v):= \lim_{u \uparrow v} \Delta_{u,v}$
>   exists. **Then** 
>   $$c(x)= \sup_{q \in G} [ D_{-c}(q)(x-q) +c(q)] = \sup_n (a_nx+b_n)$$
>   for some sequences $(a_n), (b_n) $.

I can deduce  $ c(x) \ge D_{-c}(q)(x-q)+c(q)$ for all $x \in G$ but not equality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reverse estimate follows from picking $q = x$ in the supremum:
$$
    \sup_{q \in G} [ D_{-c}(q)(x-q) +c(q)] \ge  D_{-c}(x)(x-x) +c(x)
    = c(x)
$$

For the second part, let $(q_n)$ be an enumeration of the rational
numbers in $G$ (or any sequence which is dense in $G$), and define $(a_n)$, $(b_n)$ via
$$
 a_n x + b_n = D_{-c}(q_n)(x-q_n) +c(q_n) 
$$
and
$$
 s(x) = \sup_n { a_n x + b_n }
$$
Then $s(x) \le c(x)$, and for any $n \in \Bbb N$ equality holds
at $x = q_n$ because
$$
 s(q_n) \ge a_n q_n + b_n = c(q_n)
$$

Both $c$ and $s$ are convex functions on an open interval, and therefore continuous.
It follows that $s(x) = c(x)$ for all $x \in G$.